# Where Can I start learning / taking some online courses on remote sensing, processing the remote sensing data and general space technology basics?

Tags: remote-sensing

Would like to learn about processing the remote sensing data. As of now I have started with sentinel data. But would like to know more to understand all the terms involved in it completely. 
Looking for basic resources to start with.

Comment: Maybe you could try the google.

Comment: I disagree with that last comment. There is nothing wrong with asking knowledgable people for some hints where to look first. But posting a question in Stack Exchange is not the optimal way to go about it as the question is pretty broad and the  answers may be primarily opinion based.

Comment: I can recommend you browse questions in [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) or [Earthscience SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) or other SE sites, or even ask questions in the sites' chat room [GIS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) or [What on Earth](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13909/what-on-earth). When you are ready to ask a specific question that has a well-defined answer, then go for it!

Comment: Here's a list of free resources and courses for starting out with GIS: https://www.gislounge.com/learn-gis-for-free/